# Rails hosting providers

Tags: web-hosting

What are some of the best hosting providers for a Ruby on Rails application?

I have looked into Heroku and it looks like a good option, but would it be better to go with a VPS or Grid hosting provider.

Comment: Community wiki?

Comment: This is probably best asked on a forum, just like questions similar to "what are your experiences with [xyz] web host?". Its too much of a discussion.

Comment: If I wasn't a mod, I'd vote to close on this one; there's no "right" answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends on what you're looking for.

If you'd like to have complete control over your server, I'd recommend any one of the very good Linux VPS hosting services.  In particular, [Linode](http://www.linode.com/) has really good price-to-spec ratios on their VPS machines, and I've also had good luck with [Rackspace Cloud](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/).

If you're looking for a more hands-off approach, [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) is really good as is [Engineyard](http://www.engineyard.com/) (if you can afford it).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is essentially a grid/cloud/vps hosting provider, as they're based off of Amazon's EC2 which consists of Xen virtual machines. You are just confused about marketing lingo.

Heroku is good, and there's also Engineyard, which is pretty popular.

Answer (score 1):

Another "it depends" answer, but it really does.

The pricing point of Heroku is easily great for small sites.  Once you get into more "application" based rails sites, you might want to look at Slicehost or some other VPS provider.

From there, full servers (Site5, Hostgator) might be the answer.

Ask yourself how much horsepower you really need for your site.  If you can estimate this well, you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Tilted](http://tilted.com) for a Rails app and its great. They're also very friendly and A+ support. A more popular alternative, recommended by my co-worker, would be Rackspace.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for quick easy get started, and good price, I cant [recommend Heroku strongly enough](http://heroku.com) because they enable you to create and upload your application for free and only once it starts getting traffic and you are in a position to monetise it do they start charging.

I wasted a fair amount of cash last year with a few small apps I was trying out, and engineyard charged me a fortune for them. I'm sure if you have a large application that is already a success then its fine. Didnt think much of their sales support team either.

So far Heroku have been wonderful, product support is polite and prompt - sometimes takes a little while to answer but I'm sure if you are a paying customer you'd get better service.